# How to create package from module created by Module Builder

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a module from Module Builder.
I now want to create an installer which on uploading installs this module.
Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using community edition please follow these steps
1) Log into SugarCRM as an administrator.
2) Click on Admin in the top right hand corner of SugarCRM’s interface.
3) Select Module Loader.
4) Click Choose File to select the download file.
5) Select the file
6) Click Install.
7) Click Commit.